# Order and Limit for the Includes Table - Direction "{:processed_on=>:desc}" is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the followings

> users has_many metrics

I want to find all the users with `1 row` of the `metrics` with `order('processed_on desc')` and `limit(1)`

What i am trying

```
User.includes(:metrics).where(status: 'active').order(:metrics => { processed_on: :desc }).limit(1)
```

Error:

Direction "{:processed_on=>:desc}" is invalid. Valid directions are: [:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the hash syntax with `order`, instead pass SQL directly:

```
User.includes(:metrics).where(status: 'active').order('metrics.processed_on DESC').limit(1)
```

You may still get an error from your database along the lines of `relation metrics missing in FROM clause`. If so, add a `references(:metrics)` statement to your query as well:

```
User.includes(:metrics).references(:metrics).where(status: 'active').order('metrics.processed_on DESC').limit(1)
```

Also, calling `.limit(1)` will return an array of length one. You might want to consider just using `.first` instead.

Comment: I think you can use hash syntax in the order clause from ActiveRecord 4 on

Comment: You can the hash syntax, but it won't work if the hash is nested unlike queries in the `where` or `joins` clause.